# compiling boost 1.55 with c++11

Tags: c++, boost

I decided to upgrade all my c++ apps to c++11, but not sure if I should do some special step when building boost 1.55 with gcc4.8.1.
Should I enable c++11 option when compiling boost code?

Comment: Did you try compiling without adding in the special options? What happened?

Comment: I tried, one app worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using c++11 compiled boost for around a year already and it works mostly fine (if everything else is also compiled with c++11 set, otherwise ABI compatibility problems may surface - see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility).

Also, while there's an ongoing work to make use of C++11 features in the various components of Boost framework, the progress is very uneven. Thus you may want to check first, whether the components you're interested in are already making use of any C++11 improvements.

Comment: I am using clang 3.4, change from gcc to clang because the compilation error did usually confuse me.

Comment: I compiled it successfully just now. 
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=system,filesystem,log,thread --with-toolset=clang
./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11"

Comment: Same thing. I've got alternative trees compiled with clang, everything else still applies (clang++ relies on gcc for its libstdc++).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to compile all c++ dependencies using c++11 & clang